# When Parsing JSON TO HTML Table Getting Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am using jQuery Load method to fetch an external JSON. Then trying to show the contents of it as HTML table.

The json file "product.json" is -

```
[
  {
    "User_Name": "John Doe",
    "score": "10",
    "team": "1"
  },
  {
    "User_Name": "Jane Smith",
    "score": "15",
    "team": "2"
  },
  {
    "User_Name": "Chuck Berry",
    "score": "12",
    "team": "2"
  }
]
```

On my html page i have a button, when clicked i do jQuery Load method to fetch this json into a div. Then i have to show this json as HTML table.

The HTML page code is:

```
 <button id="productButton">Try</button>
 <div id="productDiv"></div>
 <table>
     <tr>
         <th>User_Name</th>
         <th>score</th>
         <th>team</th>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

The jQuery Code:

```
$("#productButton").click(function (e) {
   $("#productDiv").load("product.json", function (response, status, xhr) {
       var json = $("#productDiv").html();
       var tr;
       for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
           tr = $('<tr/>');
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].User_Name + "</td>");
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].score + "</td>");
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].team + "</td>");
           $('table').append(tr);

           if (status == "error")
               $("#textNoData").html("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
       }
   });
});
```

The attached image showing the problem - 
[image]

The json is not parsed to HTML table i get undefined in the table. What is wrong?

Comment: What is `json.length` ? `json` is the HTML in your code.

Comment: first json is read and shown in a div - this part is successful. Then i try to read the json from the div and then parse it to table - this is unsuccessful !

Comment: I didn't ask due to lack of knowledge. I asked becuase you have a mistake. there is no point in json.length where json is the html  itself.

Comment: Why don't use `$.getJSON` instead `$.load`? You get the JSON parsed already.

Comment: @JuanPicado thank you for letting me know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the json as a string, you have to parse it before

Like this:

```
 var json = JSON.parse($("#productDiv").html());
```

Comment: I insist with the `$.getJSON`. It's cleaner.

Comment: Absolutely, I just provided a quick fix, not the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#productDiv").html()` returns a string, not a JSON object. You could either use the response parameter of the callback or `JSON.parse($("#productDiv").html())` to convert the String into a JSON object.

---

If you don't need to display the JSON text somewhere you could also use [`$.getJSON()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead to avoid inserting the response into some DOM element.

For Example:

```
$.getJSON("product.json", function(json, status) {
    if (status === "error") {
        $("#textNoData").html("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
        return;
    }

    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].User_Name + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].score + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].team + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over `json`, use `response` in for loop ie `response[i]`. If that doesn't work, before loop, do `response = JSON.parse('response');`